# Can disabling _default sink in GCP , will affect my other logs of resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I want to disable the _default sink of google cloud logging because of high cost, but wanted to be sure if this will affect my other logging policy that I am using for load balancer using big query.

Is there any affect of disabling _default sink in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

After disabling this sink any logs that will occur will not be captured by this sink and will be lost unless there are other sink that captures the logs. A warning also shows this description before you disable the sink.

You can check the description of the _default sink [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#stopping_logs_ingestion). 
You can see steps of creating sinks in the same document link above.

Comment: Inclusion filter on my default sink :  NOT LOG_ID("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND NOT \
  LOG_ID("externalaudit.googleapis.com/activity") AND NOT \
  LOG_ID("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event") AND NOT \
  LOG_ID("externalaudit.googleapis.com/system_event") AND NOT \
  LOG_ID("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency") AND NOT \
  LOG_ID("externalaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency")

Comment: As much I understand these _default sink is generally for compliance related log, if I will disable , will it  be affect my other running resources log, is there any connection with other logging option. Like I am having one logging for load balancer with bigquery